# Scripting using a transaction

Tags: sql-server

I have a question but I can never get a clear answer. Any stored
procedure that used a transaction that  I have looked at up until my recent job always had a commit transaction + a roll back in case of error. However I have seen a lot of code
at my new job that just has a begin transaction and then a commit at the end with no roll back. I understand why you would use a transaction with a rollback but why would you want to begin a transaction with no roll back? Is it so when you run that code you want to lock the table up so no values can be changed why your code is updating? If so why would you not want the added security of a roll back in case something goes wrong? Is this proper use of the transaction statement? Any thoughts or ideas would be great!

For Example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION [Tran1]

INSERT INTO [Test].[dbo].[T1]
    ([Title], [AVG])
VALUES ('Tidd130', 130), ('Tidd230', 230)

UPDATE [Test].[dbo].[T1]
  SET [Title] = N'az2' ,[AVG] = 1
  WHERE [dbo].[T1].[Title] = N'az'

COMMIT TRANSACTION [Tran1]
GO
```

shouldn't this code be using a roll back syntax for proper use of the begin transaction statement?

Comment: do they have SET XACT_ABORT ON ?

Comment: I suggest you post a cutdown example...it's hard to comment on code we haven't seen...

Comment: Added an example, thank you sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is that if that set of transactions needs to be "all or nothing", wrapping the lot in a transaction is the way to ensure that is what will happen. You're not seeing an explicit rollback because that's not what they're guarding against. Imagine the ff scenario with your contrived example:

1. The insert happens
2. The server crashes (or the log fills up or some other external reason why things can't continue) before the update can happen

If they're both wrapped in the same transaction, the insert won't be reflected in the table data. Which is the desired behavior.

Comment: The server crashing could be the best thing that happens from a 'debugging' point of view. What if the process gets an error but doesn't crash and doesn't commit but proceeds and holds the connection open for a while? All the resources it uses are locked until something happens to end the connection or an 'end transaction' statement occurs.  Debugging these faults can be 'interesting'.

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. If you know that your application sets the xact_abort property of all of the connections that it makes to on, then any error will end the transaction and release the resources.

Comment: So what if the insert happens and the update happens but one of the columns got an error or couldn't be updated? It would roll back to the original state because there is no roll back correct?

Comment: I just ran a test and if xact_abort isn't on, the insert commits even if the update fails (in my case on a check constraint). There are two options: wrap it in a try/catch or set xact_abort on.

Answer (score 0):

You use transaction when you need the outcome to be [atomic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29), you would see this alot in financial related procedures where you are gravely worried about data [acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) consistency .  Otherwise it is not necessary and introduces a great deal of locking overhead.  There is a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317866/when-to-use-transactions-in-sql-server) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46261/dont-use-a-transaction-for-stored-procedure) that goes into great depth.

### Edit

The takeaway point is if the procedure is a all or none and must either succeed or fail the correct decision is to use a transaction.  If the procedure is not a all or none transaction such as simple insert update etc using a transaction is a) unnecessary and b) can introduce an undue performance overhead due to additional locking.

Comment: I'm curious why the downvote on this one? I came here to say more or less the same thing. Committing (or not) more than one statement in a transaction is a perfectly legitimate use!

Comment: 1. Doesn't address the question. 2. Implies that transactions are inherently atomic, which is incorrect. The transaction referenced in the question is in fact non-atomic.

Comment: @JonTirjan A Transaction by definition is atomic http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction and also the transaction he posted is also atomic if the update fails the insert will be rolled back.

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna   Sorry, but you're incorrect.  In the above example, if the `UPDATE` fails, the `INSERT` is not rolled back.  If you don't believe me, run the script yourself.

Comment: "A database transaction, by definition, must be atomic, consistent, isolated and durable.[1] Database practitioners often refer to these properties of database transactions using the acronym ACID." ~Definition

Comment: [Technet - Controlling Transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175523(v=sql.105).aspx) --- If a run-time statement error (such as a constraint violation) occurs in a batch, the default behavior in the Database Engine is to roll back only the statement that generated the error. You can change this behavior using the `SET XACT_ABORT` statement. After `SET XACT_ABORT ON` is executed, any run-time statement error causes an automatic rollback of the current transaction.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not doubting that database transactions in general are supposed to be atomic. I am however suggesting that SQL Server's implementation of transactions is not truly atomic.

Answer (score 0):

When transactions are not explicitly declared, SQL Server will automatically `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` a `TRANSACTION` for each command.  This frees up each command's lock as soon as the command executes.

When executing multiple commands inside a single transaction (as in the example you posted), locks from all commands are held until the transaction is committed.

Depending on the desired behavior, the script you posted may be correct.  However, I would be cautious to ensure that the developer did not mistakenly believe that the transaction would be automatically rolled back on error.  If that behavior is desired, you do indeed need to explicitly `ROLLBACK` or `SET XACT_ABORT ON`